# Android - Chinese Zodiac App - How to attack this

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist, datepicker

I'm trying to create an Android app to determine a user's Chinese Zodiac sign, going by the chart located here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac#Chinese_calendar

I'm receiving input from the user in a DatePicker widget which gives me an integer for each the month, day, and year.  I have created an object, lets call it ZOD, which has a integer variable for the day, month, and year.

To start off, I'd like to explain the first approach that came to mind for me.  I'm thinking that i will have an ArrayList of my ZOD class that holds all of the dates.  for example, the spot 0 will be the date "Feb 5, 1924" (2,5,1924) and the spot 1 will be "Jan 23, 1925" (1,23,1925) etc...

Lets assume the user's input is a ZOD object called 'input', with their values inputted.  I was thinking i could loop through the arrayList with a for loop (int i =0; etc) and first i would compare the year

```
if(input.year >= ZOD(i).year  &&  input.year <= ZOD(i+1).year)
{

}
```

so essentially, i think that would give me the correct spot for the year.  could i continue this pattern and have two more if statements, one for the month, and one for the day, and hope for a correct match?  edit: just from typing this out and looking over the notes i am making, i can tell this method will not work.   for ALL of the zodiac dates, the month is either January or February.

I dont have any overall question to ask, i hope my post sums up what i am looking for and trying to do. i just need advice or suggestions.

Comment: On this site you should have an "overall" question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably much simpler to translate the dates into integer numbers of days, or just pairs of `java.util.Date` objects, rather than trying to create your own date representation.

You can then compare your input day with these ranges, comparing against the start and end until you find a match. You could store explicit ranges (pairs of numbers/Dates) or you could store start and end values in two parallel arrays of the same length.

(It's probably also possible to speed things up using binary search or similar, but unlikely to be worth the effort).

I am assuming here that there isn't a simple formula for determining the Calendar, hence the need to do look-ups. If there's some formula for constructing the calendar then you could implement that instead.